# Converting the result of pgr_dijkstra routing to an encoded polyline

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have this query for routing which is working, and would like it to give me an encoded polyline as a result instead of segmented geometries because I want to display it easily on a mobile Google MapView.

```
Select geom from pgr_dijkstra(
 'Select gid as id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost from network', 1,3000, false) as di
 JOIN network pt
 ON di.edge = pt.gid ;
```

As I understand I must use `ST_AsEncodedPolyline()` function but I don't understand how to use the result of `pgr_dijkstra()` in a way it be used as parameter for `ST_AsEncodedPolyline()`.

Answer (score 2):

Just `ST_Union` the results:

```
SELECT ST_AsEncodedPolyline(ST_Union(geom), 5) AS enc
FROM   pgr_Dijkstra(
         '
          SELECT gid AS id, source, target, ST_Length(geom) AS cost
          FROM network
         ',
         1,
         3000,
         FALSE
) AS   di
JOIN   network AS pt
  ON   di.edge = pt.gid
;
```

While `precision := 5` is the default, it is good to remember what precision you used; if the decoding application uses a different value, your geometries become useless. As per the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEncodedPolyline.html) docs, *Google Maps* uses a coordinate precision of 5.

`ST_Collect` performs *a lot* faster than `ST_Union`, but does not dissolve any imprecision (e.g. overlaps) in the collected set of *LineStrings*; given only a single (or a few) routes, with a few hundred segments or so, the difference will likely be neglect-able.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  However I get this error : "ERROR:  Only SRID 4326 is supported."

Comment: @GregoryNowik right: if your data has an SRID assigned (which it should) you need to `ST_Transform(ST_Union(geom), 4326)`.

Comment: Ok so it's not an issue anymore using ST_SetSRID instead of ST_Transform (which doesn't work because the geom doesn't have an SRID at all).

Now I'm running into another error : "lwgeom_to_encoded_polyline: 'MultiLineString' geometry type not supported".  The  [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEncodedPolyline.html) for the ST_AsEncodedPolyline function doesn't give any information about which geom type is supported and which is not so i don't understand why a MultiLineString would cause an problem...